# I keep getting RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/. How do I successfully create user profiles in Django via a one to one relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to extend the built-in user and add some more information to it. I have two apps in my django project- general and user_details. Inside my user_details app, in the models.py file, I have the following...

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from general.models import Ward

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    loc_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True) 
    ward = models.ForeignKey(Ward, related_name="wards", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User details"

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```

I have successfully done this before but today for some reason when I try to log in via the django admin, I keep getting the `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/, no such column: user_details_profile.id`. There are no other components involved, no views or any of that. It's just models and the admin panel. I'm trying to get the model to show in the admin panel but I ran into this error every time I try to log in.
Here is the traceback http://dpaste.com/0W7653C. 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please and how I can get it to work. Help.

Comment: Please share the related view.

Comment: The error is located somewhere else (based on the error message), please provide the *full* traceback.

Comment: I have updated my question. I get the error when I try to log in via the django admin log in area. I don't have any other components like views involved.

Comment: but the part of the error that you show, seems to indicate that the error is located somewhere else. You can use the traceback (I advise to share the *full* traceback) to find out what parts of your software are causeing this error.

Comment: I've shared a link in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you define a `OneToOneField` that does *not* mean that every object of the targeted model contains an object from the referencing model. A `OneToOneField` in essence is a `ForeignKey` with a `unique=True` (and some extra logic to do proper naming).

Here it thus means that although every `Profile` has a related user, *not* every user has a `Profile`. It is possible that there are `User`s for which *no* `Profile` exists.

If you thus query `some_user.profile` there are two scenario's that can unfold:

1. there is a related `Profile` object that is the fetched, and returned; or
2. there is no such object, and then it raises a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error.

There have been some proposals to return `None` in the latter case, but due to *backwards* compatibility, this will probably not be implemented in the (near) future, or implemented at all.

So you probably have a user for which there is no profile. Based on the full traceback, the error happens on the line `instance.profile.save()`. We can fix this by creating a profile in case there is no such profile:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.profile.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

We thus check if the `instance` has a `.profile` that leads to a `Profile` object. In case it has not, it will raise an exception, and then we create one.

This is also more in the **E**asier to **A**sk **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission (EAFP) spirit of Django.

Comment: That worked! It got me past that error but now I am met with OperationalError at /admin/login/ no such column: user_details_profile.id. Traceback http://dpaste.com/324C9HA

Comment: Did you properly migrate the project?

Comment: @NelsonKing: well the error is a similar one as `create_user_profile`, except for the `save_user_profile` signal.

Comment: Yes. The project is properly migrated. Regarding your latter comment, how do I solve the issue with the `save_user_profile` signal? I'm really new to django.

Comment: @NelsonKing: well exactly the same way: wrap the `instance.profile` part in a `try`-`except` and handle it by creating a profile if it fails. I think however that it might be beneficial to look up some basic Python concepts, since this makes it easier to understand what is happening behind the curtains.

Comment: It finally worked! And I realize that I have some more reading to do on python. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. It will work

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.profile.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else might face this same problem: Try creating a python file in the app of your project that's implementing the registration or sign up and call it "signals.py" and add the following code snippet to it. It worked for me perfectly.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

  @receiver(post_save, sender = User)
  def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user = instance


  def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  instance.profile.save()
```